# How to add python support for vim without destroying up all the plugins?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I started using vim earlier this summer and have recently started to add plugins. Todays challenge is to install YouCompleteMe.

**Problem:** During the installation process I noticed that my vim version (7.4) doesn't have support for python/python3.

**Question:** How can I fix this without messing up all my plugins/.vimrc file?

Will a clean install even affect my plugins/.vimrc?
I read some where that I should install 'vim-nox'.. Should I?

**My setup:** Ubuntu 16.04. Vim 7.4. Plugins are installed via Pathogen.

Thanks in advance for your replies! 
Kind regards, Edvin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your plugins are installed in `$HOME/.vim` (or MsWindows equivalent), and not into `/etc/vim` or `/usr/share/vim`, there should be no problem: you can upgrade your vim version without impacting what you have already installed.

See `:h 'rtp'` and `:h startup`.

Comment: Okey, thanks! That's what I wanted to hear. I will read up more on thoes help pages before any re-install :)

Answer (score 1):

Plugins and vimrc are just files. They can't be executed stand alone. Further, they come into power, only when vim is running.

So, your uninstallation/installation of vim doesn't change/affect plugins or vimrc. However, if the plugin or vimrc has code related to specific environment (like OS, terminal, etc,.) or needs specific features of vim and if your new version doesnt support them, you may have problems. Plugins in default folder(where vim is installed) will get deleted when you uninstall. The plugins in HOME directory aren't affected anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This was excatly what I hoped to hear :)